# Firebase Push Notification not received

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I'm not very much familiar with Android and Firebase. I am trying to send notification using Firebase console to my android app. It is showing nothing, not even in Log, pls help.
Here is my code:
**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private TextView txtRegId, txtMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtRegId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_reg_id);
        txtMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_push_message);

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // checking for type intent filter
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                    // gcm successfully registered
                    // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                    displayFirebaseRegId();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                    // new push notification is received

                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    txtMessage.setText(message);
                }
            }
        };

        displayFirebaseRegId();
    }

    // Fetches reg id from shared preferences
    // and displays on the screen
    private void displayFirebaseRegId() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
        String regId = pref.getString("regId", null);

        Log.e(TAG, "Firebase reg id: " + regId);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(regId))
            txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id: " + regId);
        else
            txtRegId.setText("Firebase Reg Id is not received yet!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // register GCM registration complete receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));

        // register new push message receiver
        // by doing this, the activity will be notified each time a new message arrives
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION));

        // clear the notification area when the app is opened
        NotificationUtils.clearNotifications(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {  
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance (this).unregisterReceiver 
    (mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**Config.java**

```
public class Config {

// global topic to receive app wide push notifications
public static final String TOPIC_GLOBAL = "global";

// broadcast receiver intent filters
public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "registrationComplete";
public static final String PUSH_NOTIFICATION = "pushNotification";

// id to handle the notification in the notification tray
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 100;
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE = 101;

public static final String SHARED_PREF = "ah_firebase";
}
```

**NotificationUtils.java**

```
public class NotificationUtils {

private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;

public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
}

public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
   NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

        if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && 
  Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, 
   timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            } else {
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, 
 timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            }
        }
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, 
 resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
    }
}

 private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int 
 icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent 
 resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new 
 NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)                
         .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
  mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
 }

  private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder 
 mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, 
 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new 
  NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)                
   .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
 mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, 
  notification);
 }

/**
 * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
 * the notification tray
 */
 public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
 url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
   }

// Playing notification sound
public void playNotificationSound() {
    try {
        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 */
 public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) 
 context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = 
 am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : 
 runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == 
 ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = 
 am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) 
 {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}

// Clears notification tray messages
 public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
 context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}

public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
    }else{
        // If the app is in background, firebase itself handles the notification
    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
        boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
        String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
        JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
        Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text and image
 */
private void showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, imageUrl);
}
}
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    // Saving reg id to shared preferences
    storeRegIdInPref(refreshedToken);

    // sending reg id to your server
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

   // FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("GLOBALgroup");//Try xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    registrationComplete.putExtra("token", refreshedToken);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {
    // sending gcm token to server
    Log.e(TAG, "sendRegistrationToServer: " + token);
}

private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xx.xxxxx.xxxxxxxx">

<!-- if you want to load images from the internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- if you want to load images from a file OR from the internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".landing"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".city"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".web"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>

            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- ./Firebase Notifications -->

</application>
```

Comment: When app is in background or no matter?

Comment: no matter @Yupi

Comment: You are sending the messages from firebase console?

Comment: yes. from firebase console

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by simply removing the version conflict of Google Play Services and Firbase in build.gradle

Answer (score -1):

[Click on link, it will definitely help you](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/10/android-push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-php/8/)

You would have left some dependency or any other thing,so please check all steps properly in this link given above